# Android Device Chooser - Debug column

Tags: android

When you debug from eclipse with more than one android device, you get the 'Android Device Chooser' dialog box to select with one to deploy the application to. That dialog has a 'Debug' column, what does that column mean exactly? One of my phone says 'Yes' and the other says nothing.

And second part: I assume that the phone that says 'Yes' is in some kind of debug mode and that it slows it down (it is slow!). How can I turn it off?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that that when debug in this dialog is "yes" you can debug an application regardless of whether `debuggable` is set to `true` or `false` in the manifest. This tremendously convenient sometimes. If you open up DDMS on a phone that has this set to "yes" you'll see many more running processes than on a phone with this set to "no" because the phone with it set to "no" will only display those apps with `debuggable` set to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

First off, do you mean it's slow when debugging, or the phone itself becomes slow, even when not connected? You can try disabling "USB debugging" and then turning it back on again, maybe it just didn't turn on right. You should also make sure that your phone doesn't need any special developer driver to use debug correctly.