# How do you set an Android phone to be a "debug" device?

Tags: android, adt

When I run an app from Eclipse and the Android Device Chooser comes up, some devices start with the Debug column set to `Yes`. This allows you to debug an app on the device without setting `debuggable` in the manifest to `true`. Does anyone know how to change this on the phone? I'd love to be able to set this Debug attribute set to Yes for any given phone. Any way including rooting and installing a particular ROM is a welcome suggestion if it works. Just to pre-empt it, Settings > Applications > Development and enable USB debugging is not the answer.

The only other question I found related was this: [Android Device Chooser - Debug column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757365/android-device-chooser-debug-column), but there weren't any good answers to this there.

[image: Android Device Chooser]

Comment: Is the HT16BVS00148 device rooted?

Comment: I didn't root it, but it's a pre-release phone from a manufacturer that may possibly be de facto rooted. I have full access to all directories in shell.

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much the same thing. Like I bet if you do something like, adb -s <device-that's-debuggable> root, you will get a shell. And if you do it on the non debuggable one, you will get an error.

Comment: Yep, if I try to run `adb root`, I get "adbd is already running as root". I'm *pretty* sure that I've had another device which was rooted which wasn't debug though. So it's probably correlated but not 1-to-1.

Comment: Sorry I was on the train. I meant adb shell, and then type su. Like log me in as root. adb root will just start the daemon as root (that's your host machine permissions). There is probably a debug flag on at the os Image too which reports this

Comment: `su` works on the debug device. I think `adb root` is relevant actually. If I do `adb root` for a non-debug device I get "adbd cannot run as root in production builds".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I haven't been able to pin it down with definitive evidence, it seems this is due to the ROM being signed with test keys. While forums like XDA abound in mentions of test keys in relation to getting root, and you can find on StackOverflow [how to detect test keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101380/determine-if-running-on-a-rooted-device), I have as of yet been unable to find any information on what signing with test keys does. As far as I can tell though, this is one of those things.