# How can I enable/disable the Debug-mode on my Samsung device?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, adb, galaxy

This question have been asked already, but the answers seems still incomplete. The profound answers already found are the following:

1. [How do you set an Android phone to be a “debug” device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936847/how-do-you-set-an-android-phone-to-be-a-debug-device)
2. [Android Device Chooser - Debug column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757365/android-device-chooser-debug-column)

But unfortunatly non of them could explain it with absolute certainty, why or why not an Android device has debug support, btw. I don't mean the debug flag in AndoridManifest.xml files.

To check whether or not a rooted device could be managed to enable debug mode, I've rooted my Samsung Galaxy with no luck, even the rooted Galaxy S is not debuggable.

How can I enable/disable the Debug-Mode on my Samsung device?!

Thank you!

**Edit** To clarify I look for a full debug enabled device, not the USB-debugging. Due to the stupid fact stackoverflow does not allow me to post images (low repuation score), this question has a little missunderstandig. I refer to full debug mode, shown in the Android Device Chooser column labeled Debug.

**Edit2**

For completeness of question I've added the screen shot image now.

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with root, unless you have a very obscure device, perhaps one sold for a special purpose rather than general use.

Comment: @ChrisStratton May I don't make my self clear. I do not looking for USB-debugging. I would like to use my regular device in DDMS File Explorer to examine my device (but not only), hence I need to enable full debug support. The short therm "How can I enable/diable the Debug-Mode on my Samsung device?!" refers to the Debug column in Android Device Chooser. I thought my two reference links above made that clear, sorry if not.

Comment: Okay, that is controlled by properties like ro.debuggable set in init.rc, which you have to change by regenerating and reflashing the kernel/initrd combined image.  Or you can try hexediting adbd to read properties by a different name, and set them yourself from the shell (but it would be easy to break adb entirely).

Comment: +1 @ChrisStratton Thanks for the hint. You give me the right direction see [here](http://www.slideshare.net/tetsu.koba/adbandroid-debug-bridge-how-it-works). The Android build developer says about Android smartphone ADB (works under the hood of DDMS): Usually it runs on secure mode.(secure=1). Running on emulator→secure = 0.  In secure mode, all services invoked by adbd ran as SHELL user. Some causes ”permissiondenied”.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image]

All you need is to enable the USB debugging feature on your device.

Comment: Sorry but that's not the real question! If I have had enough Reputation and had been able to post an image like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936847/how-do-you-set-an-android-phone-to-be-a-debug-device) one, to clearify. Unfortuntely I had not. Please consider to full-read the question, before to give any answers. I ask for full Debug-Mode, USB debugging is the last thing of my concern. Thanks anyway, this answer may help others.

Comment: @AndreaBolm the problem is you are asking for it by the wrong name.