# android debugging when usb disconnected

Tags: android, debugging, adb, logcat

I have many `Log.i` and `Log.d` in my app. When running on real device I see log output of every log statement in `DDMS` either using session filter or no filter.

When I disconnect USB and perform actions in my app to produce `debug` log lines it does not generate output lines. Checking historical `logcat` output via `adb` I got no entry out of my app 
when running: `logcat -b events -v time -d *:*`

In manifest I have

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

Running `adb -d shell getprop` contains

```
[ro.debuggable]: [0]
```

I guess similar question relates to mine:
[How can I enable/disable the Debug-mode on my Samsung device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461001/how-can-i-enable-disable-the-debug-mode-on-my-samsung-device)

On the device (2.3.6) USB debuggig is enabled under settings-application-development.

My goal would be to get log entries generated by my app when device is not connected to computer.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do remote debugging through logcat, without the need of extra software.

1. Connect real device to computer.
2. Run `adb tcpip 5555`.
3. Disconnect the device.
4. Find out the local IP address of the android device
5. Run `adb connect 192.168.*.***`, replacing the *s with the device's local IP.

If all went well, the device should now be connected, and you can run/debug and get logcat messages.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using some kind of dedicated software for remote logging and debugging, so you can get all the logs without worrying about losing them when your device is disconnected. You can try using https://www.apphance.com/ library. It allows you to log, grab screenshots, intercept exceptions and report problems directly from your device. It doesn't matter if you have debugging enabled or not.

Comment: In fact, besides adb I'm using a logcat app on the device to check  log messages in real-time but as above mentioned, it is not in the log at all.